# Custom Validator stopping spring internal validation

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I created a validator to validate date field of any class. I autowired its instance in my controller and called it's validate() in my controller's method. Everything is working fine.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{pan}",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitIfPANpresents(@ModelAttribute("command") @Valid  PortfolioBean portfolio,bindingResult result){
    dateValidator.validate(portfolio, result);
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println(result.getErrorCount());
        return new ModelAndView("portfolioview");
    }
:
}
```

Now I created a method in my controller to bind custom validator with WebDataBinder. I did this with hope that I would have not to call validate() explicitly.

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(dateValidator);
}
```

Still everything is working fine.

Now I commented call for validate() of custom validator from controller's method and tested the code. I can see errors set from custom validator only. Spring's internal validation stops working.

What wrong I am doing or missing to do? My need is, not to call validate() explicitly and to bind validator from xml as an extra validator.

Comment: somewhere I read "JSR 303 built in annotations don't do anything When you've injected your own validator" :( any solution?

Comment: Can I do it using aspectJ or other way? I want it run automatically with one time configuration only.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `binder.setValidator(dateValidator);`, you replace Spring's validator with your `dateValidator`. That's why Spring's internal validation stops working.

So if you want both validators to work, you should remove this line and keep `dateValidator.validate(...)`. You have no choice if you want to have an extra validator.